# how to type only specific characters into inputbox by angular2, validations

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to insert only specific characters such like '7' and '8' into inputbox. When I add validations and user input type="number" and min="7" max="8", i can insert other keys but during the next process  I get validation messages. I could not find how to write specific characters before validation occurs.

Regards
Alper

My Snippet :

```
 <input type="number" min="0" max="12" name="input8">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
   <input type="number" min="0" max="12" name="input8" formControlName="input8" required>
   <span *ngIf="input8.touched && input8.errors">
    <span *ngIf="input8.errors.minlength">
    number at list 7 digit
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="input8.errors.maxlength">
    number is not greater than 8 digit
    </span>
    </span>
    </form>
```

Comment: Hello Vikram . Where I should put this code after between <input> </input> tags. I could not make it work succesfully.

Comment: you are using angular 2 final version or 1.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned it before . I am using Angular 2 Final Version

Comment: i make some some changes in form also i considered you can use formgroup and form builder in your component ..if not follow this link                 [Angular form builder](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html#!#formbuilder)

Comment: there should be an exact solution :/